# What's better practice : To keep a fileInputStream open for a long time, or open and close it a lot?

Tags: java, file-io

I've written a little app in java that writes a few lines to a text file every ten seconds or so. Is is better to initialise the input stream outside the loop and keep it open for a very long time, or to open and close it every time I need to use it?

I don't think it really matters in this example, since it's such a slow loop, but I'd like to know just for future referance. What about an identical scenario but pertaining to a JDBC connection?..

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a file stream, I think I'd keep the stream open.  If you are forever opening and closing it, there is always a remote possibility that an open might fail because someone has opened / locked the file in an editor since you last wrote to it.  (Besides, the system calls to open and close a file don't come for free ...)

For the JDBC case, you should do neither.  Rather you should use a JDBC connection pool, and let *that* take care of opening / closing the connection.  (One issue with hanging onto a database connection for a long time is that the database can close it.  Depending on your JDBC driver, this can cause problems when you try to use the closed connection.)

Comment: Ta for that insightful answer, but you can you use conncetion pools without running inside an app server?...

Comment: Yup.  There are connection pool libraries that are independent of app servers; e.g. C3PO - http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/

Comment: When keeping a file stream open like that, it's a good idea to flush() the stream after each period of writing.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - that depends on the use-case.  There are use-cases where flushing is unnecessary, and therefore a waste of resources.  But yes, you should consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your case, it happens very infrequently, once per 10 seconds. so i would like to recommend the 'stateless' implementation, meaning, open the File, do your operations then close it once you done.